# Maximize a function of $x$ and $y$ where $x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions, maximum, maximize

I have the following function:
$f(x,y) = x(y^2-x^2)- \frac{(x^2 +y^2)^2}{2\rho}+\frac{3x^2(y^2-4x^2)}{\rho}$ where $\rho>0$ is a constant.

My goal is to find the maximum value of this function subject to the constraint $x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

My thoughts:

1. I  think I can replace the second term $\frac{(x^2 +y^2)^2}{2\rho}$ with $\frac{1}{2\rho}$ since due to the constraint $x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$.

But, I am not sure how to proceed. Can someone show me the steps for solving this problem? What would be the easiest way to approach this?

Comment: Try this: `Maximize[{x (y^2 - x^2) - (x^2 + y^2)^2/(2 rho) + (3 x^2 (y^2 - 4 x^2))/rho, x^2 + y^2 <= 1, rho > 0}, {x, y}]`. And you'll see that it depends on the parameter value of $\rho$.

Comment: @ppp Is there a way to solve this in mathematical online? I am new to mathematica

Comment: I know there is a free access to Mathematica online for  students.

Comment: @wanderer For this problem you can use the free online WolframAlpha. Substitute `r` for `rho` and `Maximize[{x(y^2-x^2)-(x^2+y^2)^2/(2 r)+(3 x^2(y^2-4 x^2))/r,x^2+y^2<=1,r>0},{x,y}]` returns a solution in 15 seconds. It goes on to try to do a bunch of additional calculations and formatting, but times out before finishing that, but you got the solution before that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] := 
 x (y^2 - x^2) - (x^2 + y^2)^2/(2 ρ) + 3 x^2 (y^2 - 4 x^2)/ρ

MaxValue[{f[x, y], x^2 + y^2 <= 1, 0 < ρ}, {x, y, ρ}]

(* 1 *)

Maximize[{f[x, y], x^2 + y^2 <= 1, 0 < ρ}, {x, y, ρ}]

(* Maximize::natt: The maximum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints. 

{1, {x -> -1, y -> 0, ρ -> ComplexInfinity}} *)

f[-1, 0]

(* 1 - 25/(2 ρ) *)

Limit[f[-1, 0], ρ -> ∞]

(* 1 *)
```

**EDIT:** If `ρ` has a fixed value, the maximum is a complicated [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) expression that depends on the specific value of  `ρ`

```
max = Assuming[ρ > 0, 
  MaxValue[{f[x, y], x^2 + y^2 <= 1, 0 < ρ}, {x, y}] // FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am having some trouble understanding. Could you please explain the result? Is the maximum value 1?  What does this mean? "(* Maximize::natt: The maximum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints. 

{1, {x -> -1, y -> 0, ρ -> ComplexInfinity}} *)
"

Comment: The maximum of `1` occurs when `\[Rho]` is `Infinity`. Since `Infinity` is not a number, it cannot be used to define a point (`{x, y, \[Rho]}`), i.e., there is no point that satisfies the constraints. The maximum is arbitrarily close to `1`, i.e., the maximum is `1` in the limit.

Comment: Thanks. But, in my case $\rho$ is an unknown constant. So, for a given $\rho$, is the maximum $1-\frac{25}{2\rho}$?

Comment: No. See the edit.